# Find the names that are unique using exists or not exists

Tags: sql, subquery, distinct, exists

Table `vales`:

```
id  Name
1   rahul
2   john
3   Aswin
4   jerry
5   jack
6   john
```

I want to print unique names, ie list with out john using `Exists` or `Not Exists` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select name
from vales v
where not exists (select 1 from vales v1 where v1.name = v.name and v1.id <> v.id)
```

Note that aggregation is also a possible solution (although this does not use `exists`):

```
select name
from vales
group by name
having count(*) = 1
```